# Processed, merged values.xml of subproject not reflected in the main project values.xml

Tags: android, gradle, adt, build.gradle

I want to process merged subproject values.xml file. I have the following piece of code in the subproject build.gradle:

```
android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.mergeResources.doLast {
        File valuesFile = file("${buildDir}/res/all/${variant.dirName}/values/values.xml")
        //process the file 
    }
}
```

I can see that the file is correctly processed.

On the other hand the result of processing is not reflected in {MAIN_PROJECT}/build/exploded-bundles/{LIBRARY_PROJECT}.aar/res/values/values.xml as well as in the final merged main project values.xml file.

Any idea how I can fix the issue?